# WPF conditional convertor

Tags: wpf, converters

I have binding to Image.Source and TextBlocks. Also I have own convertor classes.

```
<conv:StatusConvertor x:Key="statusConvertor"></conv:StatusConvertor>
<conv:ImageConvertor x:Key="imageConvertor"></conv:ImageConvertor>
```

For example:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Value.profilePhoto, Converter={StaticResource imageConvertor}}" Margin="4,4,4,2"/>

<TextBlock Name="tbStatus" Text="{Binding Value.status,Converter={StaticResource statusConvertor}}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,2,2,2" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Normal"></TextBlock>
```

I want set condition for imageConvertor, for example:

```
IF tbStatus.Text=="0"
THEN use imageConvertor on Image.Source
```

It’s possible this write in XAML, maybe in convertor class?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of making your ImageConverter an IvalueConverter, make it an IMultiValueConverter:

```
<Image Margin="4,4,4,2">
    <Image.Source>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource imageConvertor}">
            <Binding Path="Value.profilePhoto" />
            <Binding Path="Value.status" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

A IMultiValueConverter is the same as an IValueConverter, except that it passes an array of objects instead of a single object value.

```
public object Convert(object[] values, 
                      Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   // Use your converter code from before, but add a check for the Status value
   // as well
   string path = values[0].ToString();
   int status = Int32.Parse(values[1].ToString();

   if (status == 0)
      return newImageSource;

   return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
}
```

Here is is tough for me to guess on the design of your current converter, but this gives you a rough idea on what to do.  I am implying from your question that if the status is not 0, you don't want your converter to return anything - hence the DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.

Comment: This mostly works... But if the converter returns an image once, Binding.DoNothing won't override that behavior.  Instead it should return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.  Also, it should return an ImageSource, as that is the property type of the Image.Source property.

Comment: Duly noted - I've updated my answer to make the return value slightly more clear, and make the correct change to UnsetValue (been using too much MVVM and not enough converters lately).  :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't specifically answer the question, but I managed to solve my problem using this question as a guide, so I thought it might help future searchers. It could probably also be extended further to solve the original question with a little more work.

I was trying to find a way of evaluating an IF-conditional expression within XAML and wanted to combine the power of a `Binding` expression and a `MarkupExtension`. Using the idea of a converter, I managed to create a `ConditionalMarkupConverter`. This has two properties to specify the values to be returned when a binding expression evaluates to `true` or `false`, and since it's a converter, it can be easily added to a binding expression.

**Converter**

```
public sealed class ConditionalMarkupConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object TrueValue { get; set; }
    public object FalseValue { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool && (bool)value)
        {
            // The given value has evaluated to true, so return the true value
            return TrueValue;
        }

        // If we get here, the given value does not evaluate to true, so default to the false value
        return FalseValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    return this;
}
```

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding IsActive, Converter={converters:ConditionalMarkupConverter TrueValue=Active, FalseValue=Inactive}}" />
```

In this example, the `TextBlock` binds to a boolean property called `IsActive` and the converter then returns the string "Active" when `IsActive` is `true`, or "Inactive" when `IsActive` is `false`.

Comment: You saved my day (or even seceral of it) !!! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do this in XAML.
I'm pretty sure it's impossible to do (as is) in the converter because you don't have access to the sender (here a TextBlock) within.

EDIT : you can do it with a multivalue converter, because you need OneWay Binding. Multivalue converters are difficult to set up with a TwoWay binding (when you need the ConvertBack method).

What I would do would be to declare two Images (one with for each value of your TextBlock : 0 and else) and bind the visibility to the textblock Text value (or directly to Value.status).

Comment: Actually, it is possible - see my answer.

Comment: My bad. I'm used to TwoWay Binding and with them you need the ConvertBack Method which is very hard to implement in a multibinding (you have to return an array of objects from a single data).